# Как добавить условие if чтоб функция срабатывала автоматически при загрузки DOM дерева?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Есть поле в форме :

```
<form class="js-ajax-form">
<input id="country_amo_url" type="hidden"  name="country" value="">
</form>
```

надо его значение заполнить ссылкой `value="http://visatravel.bz/service/visa/germany/"`
мой JQuery код не срабатывает когда ставиться условие `if`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function () {
         if($('input[name="country_amo_url"]').length){
             document.getElementById("country_amo_url").value = window.location.href; // Ivan Triumphov code Get8(amoCRM)
         }
    }());
});
```

но срабатывает когда убираешь if

```
(function () {

             document.getElementById("country_amo_url").value = window.location.href; // Ivan Triumphov code Get8(amoCRM)

    }());
```

Проверка обязательно так как возникает ошибка на страницах, где  `<input id="country_amo_url" type="hidden"  name="country" value="">` отсутствует

Answer (score 4):

```
if($('input[name="country_amo_url"]').length){
```

у Вас имя поля `country`

Comment: да спасибо ....теперь работает